# Replacing Repeating Elements

Tags: python, list

I have a list that's include repetitive elements. I need to change repetitive elements to `ElementNameElementNum`.

Example:

```
["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "a"]
```

How can I change this array to:

```
["a4", "b3", "c2", "a"]
```

There is 4 a that is repeating, 3 b and 2 c is repeating back to back too. But last a is not repeating so it will stay as "a".

Comment: this is just run length encoding, search for that

Comment: also, create a new list that you add to instead of trying to replace elements in the original list

Comment: @Guimoute that doesn't work for this, it renders `Counter({'a': 5, 'b': 3, 'c': 2})` and doesn't look like that class can make the desired output. Also you need the edgecase for `1` but that's a simple ternary

Comment: @Guimoute clearly, you didn't read my message. `Counter` objects cannot have the same key multiple times, only one key with a value of numbers. [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). it won't work with the example since there are separate groups of "a"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools

lst = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "a"]
result = []
for item, group in itertools.groupby(lst):
    count = sum(1 for _ in group)
    result.append(f"{item}{count}" if count > 1 else item)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['a4', 'b3', 'c2', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
arr = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a"]

cur = arr[0]
count =0
out = []

for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i]== cur:
        count+=1
    else:
        if count == 1:
            out.append(cur)
        else:
            out.append(cur+str(count))
        count=1
        cur = arr[i]        


if(arr[i]==arr[i-1]):
    out.append(cur+str(count))
else:
    out.append(cur)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
['a4', 'b3', 'c2', 'a']
```

My idea is just to count when the elements are the same, and write to a new array with the previous character and its count when they are different. I need the last if-else to make sure the last set of characters are written.